# JOIN horizontally with mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query 2 tables, one with students and another table containing the comments related to the student.

Student table:

```
| ID | Name |
-------------
| 1  | John |
| 2  | Alex |
```

Comment table:

```
| ID | Student ID | Comment |
-----------------------------
| 1  | 1          | phoned  |
| 2  | 1          | emailed |
| 3  | 2          | phoned  |
| 4  | 2          | emailed |
| 5  | 2          | mailed  |
```

My desired output would be something like this:

```
| Student | Comment 3 | Comment 2 | Comment 1 |
-----------------------------------------------
| John    | null      | phoned    | emailed   |
| Alex    | mailed    | emailed   | called    |
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many different type of comments are possible ?

Comment: I would like to set a limit of 5, order by ID DESC for example

Comment: and the comments are plain text, this can be everything

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be as follows:

```
SELECT students.name, c1.comment, c2.comment, c3.comment FROM students
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment = 'phoned') as c1
ON c1.student_id = students.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment = 'emailed') as c2
ON c2.student_id = students.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment = 'mailed') as c3
ON c3.student_id = students.id
```

You'll have to increase the number of joins for each comment type.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't know the value of comment a priori, this can be anything...

Comment: Then you should not follow this approach. It will be very difficult to get the output as you have mentioned. You are better off using simple group and then later change the representation in PHP or any other server code you might be using.